# Set form_for width in rails?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code for my edit.html.erb:

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
<div class="row">
  <br />
  <div class="span12">
    <h2>Main content</h2>
    <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
  <div id="errorExplanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>
    <h1>New post</h1>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :Title %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </div>
   <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :content %><br />
      <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => "40", :cols => "40" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :slug_url %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :slug_url %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :Project %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :project %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :Desciption %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :desc %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

On my webpage when it loads the form_for stuff is super skinny and won't break out of a very narrow section. When I got to inspect element and I look at the h2 it spans the whole 12 columns, but everything else doesn't. I can adjust the col number on the text area and it does nothing. It looks like it is defaulting to the the smallest text_field for it's width.

Any ideas on how I can figure out what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the other answers mention, this should be handled by your CSS. Though it's difficult to know exactly without knowing the intracicies of your stylesheet, something like this:

```
.edit_post input[type=text], .edit_post textarea {
  width: 100%;
  /* or */
  width: 450px;
}
```

will probably work.

Comment: I gave you the green checkmark because you were the first to respond. Everyone else has the right idea though too, it's on line 630 of twitter bootstrap if anyone else comes across and is using bootstrap.

Comment: I should point out, I was in fact the last to respond. Answers are ordered randomly in the case of a 'tie' - look at the timestamp to see when answers were posted. I'd suggest though that time of post is generally a bad yardstick - better to go with what you found most helpful :).

Comment: They were all equally helpful. Everyone pointed me in the right direction, but without more information no one could go beyond that. I agree that the first to post is a very bad yardstick, but I'd hate to not award it to someone.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<%= f.text_field :title, :style => "width:100px;" %>
```

It works for me and you can change the '100px' depend on your needs.

Comment: Downvoting: inline styles are a bad idea. Use an external stylesheet instead.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect your CSS. This is a pure CSS issue and has nothing to do with Rails.

(Bonus tip: Try Haml instead of ERb.)

Comment: I'll hopefully be using HAML 100% in the future. I really do like it, but I'm trying to just bang this out quickly, and most examples I find on the web are in ERB.

Comment: Learn to translate in your head. It's not difficult. Failing that, use `html2haml`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you haven't specified any sort of widths, unless you did in your stylesheet, which you didn't include in your post.
Are any of the lines wrapping (like the titles < h1 > or < h2 >) ?  If they are and that's not what you want, you can add "white-space:nowrap:" to your h1/h2 styles in your stylesheet.
I also noticed you are looping and adding a list (< li >). Try specifying a width in the < ul > tag to force it to be the same width as the header tag (maybe width:100%;).
Just some ideas since I don't know what your stylesheet looks like :)